# angularjs calling an inner function within service results in undefined

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular. I have a service where I call a function by another function within the service. But in my controller is shows as undefined. See below

```
//my Service
myApp.service("LocationService", function() {
    var srv = {}
    srv.msg = {long:0, lat:0};

    srv.onSuccess = function() {
        this.msg.lat = 32;
    },

    srv.onError = function() {
        this.msg.long = 99;
    },

    srv.getGpsFix = function() {
        this.onSuccess();//fails in controller
    }

    return srv;
});

//my Controller
myApp.controller("MusicCtrl", ["$scope", "LocationService", function($scope, LocationService) {

//undefined
    console.log(locationService.getGpsFix());

}]);
```

Comment: Terminate your function assignments with semicolons. So instead of `srv.onSuccess = function() { /* ... */ },`, do `srv.onSuccess = function() { /* ... */ };`.

Comment: @Jackson this should be an answer.

Comment: @Jackson I changed to semicolons at the end but I still get the undefined result.
output of call console.log(LocationService.getGpsFix()); //undefined
console.log(LocationService.msg); //lat is changed to 32

Comment: Sure. I recommend that, in general, you use semicolons to terminate statements. My original suspicion was that that was the cause of the error, because frequently poor line termination is the cause of errors, but for this issue I think my posted Answer should help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct that `locationService.getGpsFix()` would return `undefined`.

If you intended for it to return a value, then use the `return` keyword in your function.

```
srv.getGpsFix = function() {
    this.onSuccess();
    return 'It worked!!!';
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`locationService.getGpsFix()` is `undefined`. In your controller, your service is available as `LocationService`. Hence, use `LocationService.getGpsFix()`